# Moving to the start of a code line: Emacs

Tags: emacs

I use emacs for development and very often need to move to the start of a line (<kbd>C-a</kbd>). However if the line is indented, I'd like to move to the point at which code starts.

So while browsing code: `( ) for x in xy|z:`. On typing <kbd>C-a</kbd> we get this: `|( ) for x in xyz:`. But instead, I would like this:`( ) |for x in xyz:`

Here | indicates cursor and () indicate spaces or tabs.

How can I make make this happen?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/48121/is-there-an-emacs-command-to-go-to-end-of-code-line-before-line-comment-and-whi/48160#48160

Answer (score 88, accepted):

<kbd>Meta</kbd>-<kbd>m</kbd>

Comment: By default, Meta-m runs `back-to-indentation`.

Comment: Shortest (and most correct) answer I have ever seen! Luckily you wrote `Meta`  and not `M-m`

Answer (score 32):

A favorite way for me to handle this is to have <kbd>C-a</kbd> toggle between the beginning of the line and the beginning of the code.  You can do so with this function:

```
(defun beginning-of-line-or-indentation ()
  "move to beginning of line, or indentation"
  (interactive)
  (if (bolp)
      (back-to-indentation)
    (beginning-of-line)))
```

And add the appropriate binding to your favorite mode map:

```
(eval-after-load "cc-mode" 
     '(define-key c-mode-base-map (kbd "C-a") 'beginning-of-line-or-indentation))
```

Answer (score 22):

I do the same toggling trick as Trey, but defaulting to indentation instead of to beginning of line. It takes slightly more code because there's no "at-beginning-of-indentation" function that I know of.

```
(defun smart-line-beginning ()
  "Move point to the beginning of text on the current line; if that is already
the current position of point, then move it to the beginning of the line."
  (interactive)
  (let ((pt (point)))
    (beginning-of-line-text)
    (when (eq pt (point))
      (beginning-of-line))))
```

This will probably let you continue to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> and have it do what you want most often, while still being able to get the built-in behavior easily.

Comment: In your solution I am having trouble where it the line is commented out it jumps 2 character inside of the comment character. Please see: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/66590/18414

Comment: @alper I like that behavior. The two things I might do from the beginning of a comment line are: delete the whole line with C-k; edit the comment's text. I can't think of any reason I'd want point positioned before the comment character but after indentation. Plus, there's already `M-m` if you want to go back to that spot.

Answer (score 8):

By default, <kbd>Meta-m</kbd> runs [`back-to-indentation`](http://www.gnu.org/s/libtool/manual/emacs/Indentation-Commands.html) which according to [the documentation](http://www.gnu.org/s/libtool/manual/emacs/Indentation-Commands.html) will "Move point to the first non-whitespace character on this line."

Answer (score 3):

Common idiom among modern IDE is to move at the first/last non-whitespace on second press:

```
(defun my--smart-beginning-of-line ()
  "Move point to `beginning-of-line'. If repeat command it cycle
position between `back-to-indentation' and `beginning-of-line'."
  (interactive "^")
  (if (and (eq last-command 'my--smart-beginning-of-line)
           (= (line-beginning-position) (point)))
      (back-to-indentation)
    (beginning-of-line)))

(defun my--smart-end-of-line ()
  "Move point to `end-of-line'. If repeat command it cycle
position between last non-whitespace and `end-of-line'."
  (interactive "^")
  (if (and (eq last-command 'my--smart-end-of-line)
           (= (line-end-position) (point)))
      (skip-syntax-backward " " (line-beginning-position))
    (end-of-line)))

(global-set-key [home]     'my--smart-beginning-of-line)
(global-set-key [end]      'my--smart-end-of-line)
```

This code firstly move to actual begin/end, new behavior show up on subsequent presses. So any old keyboard macros will work as expected!

Comment: Awesome. This code will reverse the order: first to beginning of code, then beginning of line.
```(defun my--smart-beginning-of-line ()
  "Move point to `beginning-of-line'. If repeat command it cycle
position between `back-to-indentation' and `beginning-of-line'."
  (interactive "^")
  (if (eq last-command 'my--smart-beginning-of-line)
      (if (= (line-beginning-position) (point))
          (back-to-indentation)
          (beginning-of-line))
    (back-to-indentation)))```