# C-a to go to the first character in emacs using ipython-mode

Tags: emacs, ipython

`C-a` brings me back to the beginning of the line. But I would like `C-a` to bring me back to the beginning of the text when writing python code.

```
if(test) :
    print 'this is a test' # here i want to C-a
```

Now, at the end of the line starting with `print` i would like to press `C-a` to go to the p of `print`, not to the beginning of the line. Which function does this in emacs?

Comment: This is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035872/moving-to-the-start-of-a-code-line-emacs

Answer (score 13, accepted):

infact there is a direct global key binding for this <kbd>M-m</kbd>

Comment: Utterly useful tip! Thanks! :-) (One never stops learning when it comes to Emacs.)

Answer (score 1):

There is 'misc-cmds.el' by Drew Adams which has the command `beginning-or-indentation`. It's probably what you are looking for. From the docstring:

```
Move cursor to beginning of this line or to its indentation.
If at indentation position of this line, move to beginning of line.
If at beginning of line, move to beginning of previous line.
Else, move to indentation position of this line.
```

Find it at http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/misc-cmds.el.

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
back-to-indentation
```

I bound it to <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-a</kbd> in my .emacs:

```
(global-set-key "\C-x\C-a" 'back-to-indentation)
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a small custom function to do this in my setup. When I press C-a and it's not at the indentation, it goes back to the indentation. If it is, it goes to the beginning of the line.

```
;; Remap C-a to more useful behaviour (a press anywhere other than at the indentation preforms the effect of back-to-indetation, otherwise, the normal C-a behaviour is used.
(global-set-key (kbd "C-a") (lambda () (interactive)
                  (let ((previous-point (point)))
                   (back-to-indentation)
                (if (equal (point) previous-point) (move-beginning-of-line 1)))))
```